# Cómo puedo separar una string, cada n caracteres?

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Teniendo una string cualquiera,

```
string = 'holacomoestás'
```

Cómo puedo separarla cada n espacios, como un `split()` pero por cada n espacios ?

de manera que esta cadena quedaria como,

```
[hola, como, estás]
```

Answer (score 10):

Realmente si quisieras que siguiera un patrón, por ejemplo que se divida cada `n` caracteres, tu última palabra (`estás`) tiene un carácter más, por lo que te aparecerá en un nuevo campo del array.

Para poder dividir el string teniendo en cuenta un número de caracteres determinado podrías utilizar la función `match` con una regex, en la cual le vas a especificar que te saque todas las iteraciones que tengan entre 1 y 4 caracteres, para que si hay algún carácter que se queda suelto, también salga en la salida y no se pierda por el camino.

Ejemplo:

```js
var texto = "holacomoestás";
console.log(texto.match(/.{1,4}/g));
```

Comment: En el match() por qué obtiene tres palabras de 4 de largo envéz de 8 palabras de 1 de largo ? si especificas 1, 4 ? , cómo funciona aquel regex ?

Comment: @J.Uchu Porque intentará sacar el máximo de caracteres cada vez y, en caso de que no pueda, sacara los caracteres restantes.

Comment: Entonces, saca el maximo y si no puede uno entre 1 - 3

Comment: @J.Uchu Exacto, no había visto tu edición del comentario. Es un rango que definimos para el caso de que no pueda sacar los 4 caracteres.

Answer (score 3):

Siguiendo el codigo de @Francisco para que no haya un carácter rezagado al final podrias agregar un opcional al final de la expresión regular:

```
var texto = "holacomoestás";
console.log(texto.match(/.{1,4}(.$)?/g));
```

Resultado:

```
[ 'hola', 'como', 'estás' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto podría valerte:

```
var myString = "holacomoestasyourkids";
var output = [];
var letters = 4;
var i = 0;

while(i < myString.length){
    console.log(i);
    var initIndex = i;
    var endIndex = i + letters;
    output.push(myString.substring(initIndex, endIndex));
    i = endIndex;
}
```

El resultado sería:

```
["hola", "como", "esta", "syou", "rkid", "s"]
```

Comment: Pero te estas llevando la s de (estas) como lo solucionarias

Comment: La pregunta es "Cada n caracteres". Yo no puedo identificar si la letra "s" corresponde a la palabra anterior o a la siguiente. Simplemente se que está en el índice[12], lo que hace que sea la primera letra de la cuarta palabra.
En mi ejemplo he puesto "cada 4 letras". Si hubiera puesto 5, el resultado hubiera sido ["holac", "ómoeñ", "stasy", "ourki", "ds"]

Comment: Si es que su pregunta es una y lo que pone como resultado es otra cosa dando entender que es lo que quisiera obtener ahí esta el detalle

Answer (score 1):

División por numero de caracteres usando **match**, el método match() se usa para obtener todas las ocurrencias de una expresión regular dentro de una cadena.

```
var str = 'holacomoestas';
var resultado = str.match(/.{1,4}/g); 
console.log(resultado) // la consola devolverá: [hola, como, está, s]
```

Con **split** solo te funcionaria si tuvieras **espacios** o comas en la cadena por ejemplo:

```
var cadena = "hola como estás",
    separador = " ", // un espacio en blanco
    arregloDeSubCadenas = cadena.split(separador);

console.log(arregloDeSubCadenas); // la consola devolverá: [hola, como, estás]
```

Ahora si quieres dividirla por palabras puedes hacerlo con **substring** poco practico:

```
   var cadena = "holacomoestás",
    cadena1hola = cadena.substring(0, 4); 
    cadena2como = cadena.substring(4, 8);
    cadenaestas = cadena.substring(8, 13); 

   var resultado = [cadena1hola, cadena2como, cadenaestas ]; 

   console.log(resultado); // la consola devolverá: [hola, como, estás]
```

Comment: Y si el array fuera de 1000 carácteres ?

Comment: Si es una cadena que conoces te han puesto varias respuestas de como solucionarlo pero si es una cadena de 1000 caracteres donde las palabras son de diferente tamaño si lo veo mas complejo

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, en realidad lo que deseas es dividir la cadena en subcadenas de `n` carácteres, una posible solución:

```
var str = 'holacomoestas';
var resultado = str.match(/.{1,5}/g); 
console.log(resultado)
```

Suponiendo un `n` de 5 carácteres, el `{1,...}` es para aquellas cadenas que no tienen una longitud multiplo de `n`.

Answer (score 0):

En JavaScripts lo haría así:

```
if(!String.prototype.splitBySize){
  String.prototype.splitBySize = function(n){
    let split = function(str, n, vec){
      if(!str || str.length <= n){
        if(str && str.length <= n)
          vec.push(str)
        return vec
      }
      else{
        vec.push(str.substr(0, n))
        str = str.substr(n, str.length-1)
        return split(str, n, vec)
      }
    }
    return split(this, n, [])
  }
}
```

Comment: Checa [answer], una explicación al código es bine vista y se agradecerá mucho